# Firebase serve only displays blank page for React application

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Hi All so basically whenever I use npm start to run the website locally it shows up without any issues.

I have now tried to try this out with firebase serve, but that sadly only brings up a blank page without any errors in the background.

The default 404 page however gets displayed when the url path has been updated.

I have the index.html file and 404.html inside the public folder. I have a separate folder called "src" that contains the React components. I also tried adding that src folder inside the public one, but there was no actual change.

Could someone let me know if I am missing something here?

index.html inside public folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js inside src folder

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
    reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {userProfile: 'users', useFirestoreForProfile: true, attachAuthIsReady: true}),
    reduxFirestore(fbConfig) // redux bindings for firestore
  )
);

store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
  registerServiceWorker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's in your browser console? Something like, "URI is malformed" for %PUBLIC_URL%" ?